# Wireless internet connection not working following update

Tags: wireless

After updating some packages last night my wireless on my Toshiba Satellite A210 isn't working. Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this command to unblock all wireless devices:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```